# Objects that are countries or nationalities

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Some objects also happen to be countries or nationalities. Can you find what these are:

1. I am a bird and a country
2. I am a long object and a nationality
3. I am a vegetable and a nationality
4. I am a cheese and a nationality
5. I am a yogurt and a nationality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1

> Turkey

2

> Pole (from Poland)

3

> [Swede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swede_(vegetable)) (from Sweden)

4

> Swiss (from Switzerland)

5

> Greek (from Greece)

Comment: Yep you got it! I wonder if there are any others?

Comment: These are good. You can make a new puzzle with them.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I thought about that. Too bad I gave away the answers already

Comment: How about you make the puzzle and then delete your comment above ;)

Comment: ugh, why didn't I take note of those :((

Comment: The cheese could also be ro13(Nzrevpna.  Url, V'z abg fnlvat vg'f *tbbq* purrfr, ohg vg'f cerggl pbzzba.).

Answer (score 3):

I have gathered answers for everything except number 3.

Edit: Never mind, I think eyl327 got all of them now.

1. > Turkey
2. > Pole
3. > ???
4. > Swiss
5. > Greek