# Objects that are countries or nationalities (#2)

Tags: word, knowledge, wordplay, geography

A follow-up to Dmitry Kamenetsky's [Objects that are countries or nationalities](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97665/objects-that-are-countries-or-nationalities/97666).

Can you figure out what these countries and nationalities are based on the clues?

| Country | Clue |
| --- | --- |
| ? | nuts |
| ? | punched paper |
| ? | a pepper |
| ? | a gold coin |

| Nationality | Clue |
| --- | --- |
| ? | a woven carpet |
| ? | a wood patch |
| ? | an advocate |
| ? | a pastry |
| ? | a young fish |
| ? | a shiny substance |
| ?* | a great dog |

All words are valid words in the [SOWPODS dictionary](http://www.quadplex.com/Sowpods/check) with the exception of the nationality marked with ?*.

**Hint:**

> All answers, with the exception of #1 ("nuts") and #11 ("a great dog"), are nouns (by themselves) with the clue as their meaning when not capitalized.

**Hint #2:**

> The answer to #7 ("an advocate") is commonly preceded by a five-letter word. The phrase originated from a movement consisting of people of this nationality before becoming a generic term.

**Hint #3:**

> ```
>  Countries
>  _ _ _ _ _ _ = nuts
>  _ _ _ _ = punched paper
>  _ _ _ _ _ = a pepper
>  _ _ _ _ _ _ = a gold coin
>
>
>  Nationalities
>  _ _ _ _ _ _ = a woven carpet
>  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ = a wood patch
>  _ _ _ _ = an advocate
>  _ _ _ _ _ _ = a pastry
>  _ _ _ _ = a young fish
>  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ = a shiny substance
>  _ _ _ _ = a great dog
> ```

**Edit: Nationality #2 ("a rib-like form") was removed since there was an error.**

First answer to include all 11 will be accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Countries:

> **Brazil** - ([Brazil nuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_nut))
> **Chad** - (The little circles from hole punching are known as [chad](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chad_(paper)))
> **Chile** - ([chilli pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chili_pepper) - also known as a 'chile pepper')
> **Guinea** - ([Guinea coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guinea_(coin)) thats made from gold - thanks @MacGyver88!!)

Nationalities:

> **Afghan** - ([Afghan rug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghan_rug)) - thanks @El-Guest!
> **Dutchman** - (A [wood patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutchman_(repair)) used in carpentry for repairs) - thanks @DarrelHoffman!
> **Turk** - ([Young turks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Turks) was a political movement)
> **Danish** - ([Danish pastry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_pastry))
> **Brit** - ([Young herring](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/brit)) - thanks @DarrelHoffman!
> **Polish** - (As in '[polishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polishing)' - Shiny substance)
> **Argentine** - an alternative answer for shiny substance is ‘argentine’, relating to silver.
> **Dane** - ([Great Dane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Dane) - actual nationality is 'Danish' but a 'Dane' is also from Denmark.)

Comment: Country 4 could be rot13(Thvarn).

Comment: @MacGyver88 ahhhh that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Great progress! All 4 countries are correct. 'Pastry' and 'great dog' are correct. 'Shiny substance' I will accept as an alternate answer, but there is another.

Comment: @eyl327 oh wow I was certain for polish :P I've been searching for the rest (mostly looking up a list of nationalities and typing ones that seem like they could be something else into google) but nothing yet, I'll keep searching!

Comment: A young fish could be rot13(svfu rttf, vaqvpngvat pnivne, juvpu znxrf zr guvax bs **Ehffvna** pnivne)

Comment: @Prim3numbah I'd probably say that it's more from there than that's it's name. Wikipedia lists the types of that by type of fish not by country, but it could be a good idea to pursue!

Comment: @Prim3numbah, BG -- I have added a hint. Also the second nationality ("a rib-like form") was removed because of an error.

Comment: @eyl327 out of interested what was the answer? :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil The woven carpet is likely [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghan_rug).

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil The removed answer was ["costa"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/costa) which is not a nationality on its own (it is from Costa Rican)

Comment: A young fish is a rot13(oevg).  Oh, and a wood patch is a rot13(qhgpuzna).

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Smart! I've been looking through the lists of nationalities which obviosuly only include the official terms i.e. brittish, didn't consider shortened terms :)

Comment: All of the new answers are correct. Let me know if or when you would like another hint.

Comment: @eyl327 the only hint I think I’d currently want for the advocate one would be if it’s a formal nationality (like British) or a more informal one (like brit). Otherwise I’m still quite happy to keep on looking for now :)

Comment: If British is formal and Brit is informal, then the advocate one is informal.

Comment: I've looked up dozens of synonyms for "advocate" and none of them resemble a nationality, so I for one would like a hint, because I'm completely stumped.

Comment: @F1Krazy me too, but I have a feeling it’s going to be something a bit more out of the box, like the Brit and Dutchman examples

Comment: Advocate? nqibpngr pbhyq or ry fnyinqbe -- gur fnivbe ^^

Comment: @F1Kraxy et al. -- Another hint added to the post.

Comment: @eyl327 is the update correct? I can't think of many other four letter abbreviations, and this is definitely a movement. I'm not sure on the advocate part as such, but this seems to fit the hints

Comment: I think Rajeev may have got it just before me actually :)

Comment: I'll mark this one as accepted since it contains answers to all 11. With hint #3, can you figure out what word I had in mind for 'shiny substance'? The word is used for something of or resembling silver.

Comment: @eyl327 could it perhaps be ‘Argent’?

Comment: That's close. It's 'Argentine.'

Answer (score 6):

For starters,

> Chile

is a pepper,

a

> Berber (while [not exactly a nationality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berbers))

is a woven carpet

and a

> Dane

is a great dog.

Comment: The gold coins could be rot13(Oevgnaavn) but that's really a Latin country name...

Comment: 'Pepper' and 'great dog' are correct. I have something else in mind for woven carpet, though.

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer to  #7 ("an advocate")  **chicano**

- It is a valid word in  SOPODS
- An informal term for Mexican nationality
- The Chicano movement

Though I don't know the five-letter word preceding it

Okay the answer probably is **Turk**

- The phrase is Young Turk
- Advocate is used in the sense as to support
- Young Turk is defined broadly as one advocating changes within a usually established group

Comment: Good answer, but do you have a dictionary source for chicano being defined as "an advocate"? If so, this can be an alternate answer.

Comment: The word I am thinking of is defined on [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/) with an "often not capitalized" definition.

Comment: Is the answer young turk

Comment: Well done. It is indeed Young Turk.